# Map and sort data by date

Tags: javascript, date, sorting

I retrieve an array of objects and I need to format it to make it acceptable for Google Charts.  The initial data looks like so

```
[
   {
      "itemOne":111,
      "itemTwo":1,
      "itemThree":"2022-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"
   },
   {
      "itemOne":222,
      "itemTwo":2,
      "itemThree":"2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
   },
   {
      "itemOne":333,
      "itemTwo":3,
      "itemThree":"2021-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"
   },
]
```

To start the formatting, I do the following

```
const chartData = data.lastYear.map(
    (item) => ([item.itemThree, item.itemTwo, item.itemOne]),
);
```

Which now leaves me with this.

```
[
    ["2022-02-01T00:00:00.000Z", 1, 111],
    ["2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", 2, 222],
    ["2021-12-01T00:00:00.000Z", 3, 333],
]
```

I have been trying however to sort the above by date.  My current attempt is pretty bad, and obviously doesnt work.

```
 const chartData = data.lastYear.map(
    (item) => ([item.itemThree, item.itemTwo, item.itemOne]),
  ).sort((a, b) => {
    return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
  });
```

So what would be the best way to sort everything by date?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry, I was being very silly, different see that not all dates were 2022!

Comment: To sort the mapped array, `data.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let data = [
   {
      "itemOne":111,
      "itemTwo":1,
      "itemThree":"2022-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"
   },
   {
      "itemOne":222,
      "itemTwo":2,
      "itemThree":"2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
   },
   {
      "itemOne":333,
      "itemTwo":3,
      "itemThree":"2021-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"
   },
]
data.sort((a,b)=>{
    return new Date(b.itemThree) - new Date(a.itemThree);
})
```

This sorts your data array according to date.
Hope this is helpful

Comment: The sort function body can be simply `(a, b)=> a.itemThree - b.itemThree` regardless of whether the values to sort are strings or Date objects since the stringa are ISO 8601 compliant. This also sorts the original data, not the array produced by *map*. Sorting by date has been covered many, many times before.